# Extracting the value of A tag by xpath in python

Tags: python, xpath

I have a simple python script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
from lxml import html
response = requests.get('http://site.ir/')
out=response.content
tree = html.fromstring(open(out).read())
print [e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[class="group"]/div[class="groupinfo"]/a/text()')]
```

I used xpath in order to get value of tag `a` as you can see from image below...
[image]
But the output sample is not what I expected.

UPDATE
I have also the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "p.py", line 7, in <module>
    tree = html.fromstring(open(out).read())
IOError: [Errno 36] File name too long: '\n<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put `@` at the beginning of attribute name to address an attribute in XPath :

```
//div[@class="group"]/div[@class="groupinfo"]/a/text()
```

Comment: I'm not python expert, but seems that you're treating HTML content as file name. Try to pass the HTML directly : `tree = html.fromstring(out)`

Comment: Now I have this error: `AttributeError: '_ElementStringResult' object has no attribute 'text_content`

Comment: Try to remove trailing `/text()` from the XPath to select the `<a>` node instead. `/text()` will return text node which apparently doesn't have `text_content` attribute